# change Vector<float> to heightmap coordinates OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

I have a file which has terrain coordinates in it like this:

```
//The first value is how many rows and columns the map has (assuming its a square) 
5    
-0.9 -0.6 -0.4 -0.6 -0.9
-0.2 0.1 0.3 0.1 -0.3
0 0.4 0.8 0.4 0
-0.2 0.1 0.3 0.1 -0.3
0.5 -0.6 -0.4 -0.6 -0.9
```

I have put these values into a vector(float) and now need to format it so that I can render the vertices and make a terrain. How do I go about doing this?

```
std::fstream myfile("heights.csv", std::ios_base::in);

    std::vector<float> numbers;
    float a;
    while (myfile >> a){/*printf("%f ", a);*/
    numbers.push_back(a);
    }
```

Just for reference, here is the rest of my code, it's basically code for rending 2 triangles on the screen, which I plan to remove later (just trying to learn)

```
/**
 * A typical program flow and methods for rendering simple polygons
 * using freeglut and openGL + GLSL
 */

#include <stdio.h>
// GLEW loads OpenGL extensions. Required for all OpenGL programs.
#include <GL/glew.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
// Utility code to load and compile GLSL shader programs
#include "shader.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH    400
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT   400
#define VALS_PER_VERT 3
#define VALS_PER_COLOUR 4
#define NUM_VERTS 3         // Total number of vertices to load/render

using namespace std;

// Handle to our VAO generated in setShaderData method
unsigned int vertexVaoHandle;   
unsigned int vertexVaoHandle2;  

// Handle to our shader program
unsigned int programID;

/**
 * Sets the shader uniforms and vertex data
 * This happens ONCE only, before any frames are rendered
 * @param id, Shader program object to use
 * @returns 0 for success, error otherwise
 */
int setShaderData(const unsigned int &id) 
{
    /*
     * What we want to draw
     * Each set of 3 vertices (9 floats) defines one triangle
     * You can define more triangles to draw here
     */
    float vertices[ NUM_VERTS*VALS_PER_VERT ] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.0f,    // Bottom left
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.0f,     // Bottom right
            0.0f, 0.5f, -0.0f       // Top
    };

    float vertices2[ NUM_VERTS*VALS_PER_VERT ] = {
            -0.9f, -0.9f, -0.0f,    // Bottom left
            0.9f, -0.9f, -0.0f,     // Bottom right
            0.9f, 0.5f, -0.0f       // Top
    };

    float heightmap[ NUM_VERTS*VALS_PER_VERT ] = {

            -0.9f, -0.9f, -0.0f,    // Bottom left
            0.9f, -0.9f, -0.0f,     // Bottom right
            0.9f, 0.5f, -0.0f   

    };

    // Colours for each vertex; red, green, blue and alpha
    // This data is indexed the same order as the vertex data, but reads 4 values
    // Alpha will not be used directly in this example program
    float colours[ NUM_VERTS*VALS_PER_COLOUR ] = {
            0.8f, 0.7f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
            0.3f, 0.7f, 0.1f, 1.0f,
            0.8f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
    };

    float colours2[ NUM_VERTS*VALS_PER_COLOUR ] = {
            0.8f, 0.7f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
            0.3f, 0.7f, 0.1f, 1.0f,
            0.8f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
    };

    // Generate storage on the GPU for our triangle and make it current.
    // A VAO is a set of data buffers on the GPU
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexVaoHandle);     
    glBindVertexArray(vertexVaoHandle);

    // Generate new buffers in our VAO
    // A single data buffer store for generic, per-vertex attributes
    unsigned int buffer[2];
    glGenBuffers(2, buffer);

    // Allocate GPU memory for our vertices and copy them over
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*NUM_VERTS*VALS_PER_VERT, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Do the same for our vertex colours
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*NUM_VERTS*VALS_PER_COLOUR, colours, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Now we tell OpenGL how to interpret the data we just gave it
    // Tell OpenGL what shader variable it corresponds to
    // Tell OpenGL how it's formatted (floating point, 3 values per vertex)
    int vertLoc = glGetAttribLocation(id, "a_vertex");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertLoc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertLoc, VALS_PER_VERT, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    // Do the same for the vertex colours
    int colourLoc = glGetAttribLocation(id, "a_colour");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[1]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colourLoc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colourLoc, VALS_PER_COLOUR, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    // An argument of zero un-binds all VAO's and stops us
    // from accidentally changing the VAO state
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // The same is true for buffers, so we un-bind it too
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);







    // SECOND TRI




    // Generate storage on the GPU for our triangle and make it current.
    // A VAO is a set of data buffers on the GPU
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexVaoHandle2);        
    glBindVertexArray(vertexVaoHandle2);

    // Generate new buffers in our VAO
    // A single data buffer store for generic, per-vertex attributes
    unsigned int buffer2[2];
    glGenBuffers(2, buffer2);

// Allocate GPU memory for our vertices and copy them over
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*NUM_VERTS*VALS_PER_VERT, vertices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Do the same for our vertex colours
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*NUM_VERTS*VALS_PER_COLOUR, colours2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Now we tell OpenGL how to interpret the data we just gave it
    // Tell OpenGL what shader variable it corresponds to
    // Tell OpenGL how it's formatted (floating point, 3 values per vertex)
    int vertLoc2 = glGetAttribLocation(id, "a_vertex");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2[0]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertLoc2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertLoc2, VALS_PER_VERT, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    // Do the same for the vertex colours
    int colourLoc2 = glGetAttribLocation(id, "a_colour");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2[1]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colourLoc2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colourLoc2, VALS_PER_COLOUR, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);


    // An argument of zero un-binds all VAO's and stops us
    // from accidentally changing the VAO state
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // The same is true for buffers, so we un-bind it too
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    return 0;   // return success
}


/**
 * Renders a frame of the state and shaders we have set up to the window
 * Executed each time a frame is to be drawn.
 */
void render() 
{
    // Clear the previous pixels we have drawn to the colour buffer (display buffer)
    // Called each frame so we don't draw over the top of everything previous
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(programID);

    // Make the VAO with our vertex data buffer current
    glBindVertexArray(vertexVaoHandle);

    // Send command to GPU to draw the data in the current VAO as triangles
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NUM_VERTS);

    glBindVertexArray(0);   // Un-bind the VAO



    // SECOND TRIANGLE

    // Make the VAO with our vertex data buffer current
    glBindVertexArray(vertexVaoHandle2);

    // Send command to GPU to draw the data in the current VAO as triangles
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NUM_VERTS);

    glBindVertexArray(0);   // Un-bind the VAO

    // XXXXXXXX

    glutSwapBuffers();  // Swap the back buffer with the front buffer, showing what has been rendered

    glFlush();  // Guarantees previous commands have been completed before continuing
}


/**
 * Program entry. Sets up OpenGL state, GLSL Shaders and GLUT window and function call backs
 * Takes no arguments
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    //READ IN FILE//
    std::fstream myfile("heights.csv", std::ios_base::in);

    std::vector<float> numbers;
    float a;
    while (myfile >> a){/*printf("%f ", a);*/
    numbers.push_back(a);
    }


    for (int i=0; i<numbers.size();i++){cout << numbers[i] << endl;}

    getchar();
    //READ IN FILE//

    // Set up GLUT window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);              // Starts GLUT systems, passing in command line args
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 0);     // Positions the window on the screen relative to top left
    glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);    // Size in pixels

    // Display mode takes bit flags defining properties you want the window to have;
    //  GLUT_RGBA : Set the pixel format to have Red Green Blue and Alpha colour channels
    //  GLUT_DOUBLE : Each frame is drawn to a hidden back buffer hiding the image construction
    //  GLUT_DEPTH : A depth buffer is kept so that polygons can be drawn in-front/behind others (not used in this application)
#ifdef __APPLE__    
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE);
#else
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
#endif

    glutCreateWindow("Hello World!");   // Makes the actual window and displays

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Sets the (background) colour for each time the frame-buffer (colour buffer) is cleared
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

    // Set up the shaders we are to use. 0 indicates error.
    programID = LoadShaders("minimal.vert", "minimal.frag");
    if (programID == 0)
        return 1;

    // Set this shader program in use
    // This is an OpenGL state modification and persists unless changed
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // Set the vertex data for the program
    if (setShaderData(programID) != 0)
        return 1;

    // Render call to a function we defined,
    // that is called each time GLUT thinks we need to update
    // the window contents, this method has our drawing logic
    glutDisplayFunc(render);

    // Start an infinite loop where GLUT calls methods (like render)
    // set with glut*Func when needed.
    // Runs until something kills the window
    glutMainLoop();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You read in values, and then you don't do anything with them.  I am looking at your `while` loop in `main`.  Is this question about "how do I read the numbers into a 2 dimensional array?"

Comment: The question is "Now that I have my coordinated in a vector, how do I make them into a mesh to display on the screen" sorry, I am very new to OpenGL

Answer (score -1):

Actually , i could not understand what do you want to do. But maybe this helps.

Read first line and get row,col size. Allocate multidimensional array. Go ahead to read next lines. Put the values inside array that are extracted from lines.

```
std::ifstream file( "heights.csv" );
std::string line;
getline(file , line);
int ColRowSize;
line >> ColRowSize;

/// allocate map
float** data = malloc(ColRowSize * sizeof(float *));
for(i = 0; i < ColRowSize; i++)
    {
         array[i] = malloc(ColRowSize * sizeof(float));
    }
/// read from file 
for(i = 0; i < ColRowSize; i++)
    {
         getline(file , line);
         for(j = 0; j < ColRowSize; j++)
             line >> data[i][j];             
    }
```

Comment: Why introduce `malloc`, especially in a `C++` program?  Why even introduce dynamic allocation at all?   A `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` is all that's needed.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Using vectors is one of the ways. Actually,  it is easier as you show. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Basically my question is "How do I render my image using these vertices I have stored in my vector, so they display on the screen"